# How to update sno ascending order in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to `update` my column auto increment ascending order no

and my table structure is:

```
------------
sno   | name 
------------
yyyy  |  gff
------------
xxxx  |  gch
------------
oouu  |  ghc
------------
ghfd  |  hvh
------------
```

I want the result must be:

```
------------
sno   | name 
------------
1  |  gff
------------
2  |  gch
------------
3  |  ghc
------------
4  |  hvh
------------
```

I tried the following  code

```
 UPDATE table SET AUTO_INCREMENT(no)
```

I know this is wrong. Actually i mentioned  this for example. 
Please help me to solve this code.

Comment: Does it matter which name gets which number? If so, what order do you need? It's not obvious from the example.

Comment: You need to create new column as autoincrement, then remove sno column and then change new column's name to sno.

Comment: try to do it as your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to follow this three steps of query

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN sno ;
```